# Быстрый ответ в форуме vBulletin

Tags: vbulletin, форум

Добрый вечер. Наконец-то у меня дошли руки заняться [форумом](http://i-wko.net/forum/index.php), который сделан на CMS Vbulletin, но столкнулся с такой проблемой - например, если зайти в любую тему, то внизу есть элемент `<textarea>` для быстрого ответа, например [здесь](http://i-wko.net/forum/showthread.php?t=104), но в этом поле для быстрого ответа написано - **Нажмите в сообщении на иконку "Быстрый ответ" для активации этой опции** и поле не активно пока не нажмешь на иконку **"Быстрый ответ"**...

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было писать сразу, без нажатия на *иконку "Быстрый ответ"*?

Comment: Неужели на Хэшкоде нет специалистов по CMS Vbulletin, которые могут помочь по данному вопросу? Гугл так и не дал внятного ответа ;-(

Comment: А зачем тут специалист по форуму? Вы могли бы попытаться найти этот кусок кода в шаблоне, и там же посмотреть что можно сделать.

Comment: У теперь другая проблема - я не могу найти файл, в котором генерируется этот элемент `<textarea></textarea>` для *"Быстрого ответа"*

Comment: Оказалось все проще, чем я думал. Панель администратора -> Основные настройки -> Написание и редактирование сообщений -> Быстрый ответ -> Поставить "Да, Нажатие не требуется".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты б ещё на закрытый форум ссылку дал, чтоб жизнь мёдом не казалась... Пока на этом регистрировался - обматерился не один раз, но до быстрого ответа дошёл. Вопрос решается одним заглядыванием в исходник страницы, всего делов-то: убрать **disabled** и текст внутри textarea:

```
<textarea name="message" id="vB_Editor_QR_textarea" rows="10" cols="60" style="width:100%; height:100px" tabindex="1" dir="ltr" disabled="disabled">Нажмите в сообщении на иконку 'Быстрый ответ' для активации этой опции.</textarea>
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, за помощь.